# Number of binary relations of 5 elements which are asymmetric and transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory, binary

I have a set of 5 elements. I need to count how many relations of 5 elements are asymmetric and transitive and the same time. So, since there is no type of binary relations (Tolerance, Equivalence, Quasi-order, Partial order, Strict order don't correspond) I don't know which formula I should use. How to do that?
I know how to count all asymmetric relations: $3^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}=3^{10}$. But how to count how many out them are transitive?

Comment: [Deja vu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3908762/how-to-count-number-of-antisymmetric-and-transitive-binary-relations-for-5-eleme)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner well, no help in both cases